# Determine a positive semidefinite 5*5 matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I'd like to find the real parameters $\left\{a_{14},c_6,c_8,c_{10},c_{12},c_{13},c_{14},c_{15},\alpha \right\}$ in M, which is a $5\times 5$ real symmetric matrix, such that M is positive semidefinite. I assume that $\alpha\ge 1$. My idea is to use Descartes' rule of sign (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) to determine the sign of the real roots of the corresponding characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)$.

However, the coefficients of $p(\lambda)$ are rather complicated. Any reference, suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome. Thank you!

My code for $M$:

```
MatrixForm[{{(-7 + α)*Subscript[c, 15], (1/2)*((-6 + α)*Subscript[c, 14] + 7*Subscript[c, 15]), 
    (1/2)*((-5 + α)*Subscript[c, 13] + Subscript[c, 14]), Subscript[a, 14], 
    (1/2)*((-4 + α)*(-3 + α)*(-2 + α)*(-1 + α) + Subscript[c, 13])}, 
   {(1/2)*((-6 + α)*Subscript[c, 14] + 7*Subscript[c, 15]), -2*Subscript[a, 14] + (-5 + α)*Subscript[c, 12] + 
     5*Subscript[c, 14], (1/2)*(-4 + α)*Subscript[c, 10] + Subscript[c, 12] + 2*Subscript[c, 13], 
    (1/2)*((-4 + α)*Subscript[c, 8] + 3*Subscript[c, 12]), 5*(-3 + α)*(-2 + α)*(-1 + α) + Subscript[c, 10]/2}, 
   {(1/2)*((-5 + α)*Subscript[c, 13] + Subscript[c, 14]), (1/2)*(-4 + α)*Subscript[c, 10] + Subscript[c, 12] + 
     2*Subscript[c, 13], (-3 + α)*Subscript[c, 6] + Subscript[c, 10], 
    (1/4)*((-(-3 + α))*Subscript[c, 6] + 6*Subscript[c, 8] + 4*Subscript[c, 10]), 6*(-2 + α)*(-1 + α) + Subscript[c, 6]}, 
   {Subscript[a, 14], (1/2)*((-4 + α)*Subscript[c, 8] + 3*Subscript[c, 12]), 
    (1/4)*((-(-3 + α))*Subscript[c, 6] + 6*Subscript[c, 8] + 4*Subscript[c, 10]), 
    (-3 + α)*(-2 + α)*(-1 + α) + Subscript[c, 8], (1/4)*(26*(-2 + α)*(-1 + α) - Subscript[c, 6])}, 
   {(1/2)*((-4 + α)*(-3 + α)*(-2 + α)*(-1 + α) + Subscript[c, 13]), 5*(-3 + α)*(-2 + α)*(-1 + α) + Subscript[c, 10]/2, 
    6*(-2 + α)*(-1 + α) + Subscript[c, 6], (1/4)*(26*(-2 + α)*(-1 + α) - Subscript[c, 6]), 8*(-1 + α)}}]
```

Comment: Perhaps we can start from $\alpha=2$.

Comment: Let `m = {{ ... your matrix ... }}` and remove `MatrixForm` because it's presentational only.  We have `m == Transpose[m]` is `True` and `Reduce[Array[x, 5].m.Array[x, 5] >= 0, Variables[m]]` is taking forever.

Answer (score 1):

A boring solution:

```
PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[  m /. {
  α -> 2,
  Subscript[a, 14] -> 0,
  Subscript[c, 6] -> 0,
  Subscript[c, 8] -> 0,
  Subscript[c, 10] -> 0,
  Subscript[c, 12] -> 0,
  Subscript[c, 13] -> 0,
  Subscript[c, 14] -> 0,
  Subscript[c, 15] -> 0}
]
(* True *)
```

For a more interesting solution, try finding parameters that make all the eigenvalues positive by maximizing the minimum eigenvalue like so:

```
evals = Eigenvalues[m];
{err, result} = NMaximize[Min[evals], Variables[m]]
(* {0.00105605, {α -> 1.0778, Subscript[a, 14] -> 0.174339, 
  Subscript[c, 6] -> -0.258389, Subscript[c, 8] -> 0.125641, 
  Subscript[c, 10] -> 0.373052, Subscript[c, 12] -> -0.264517, 
  Subscript[c, 13] -> -0.0915956, Subscript[c, 14] -> 0.133419, 
  Subscript[c, 15] -> -0.0302445}} *)

PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[m /. result]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 1. I just used my Macbook air (2011) to run your code. However, it run and never got any result. (But your numerical result is true). 2. I used your code under $\alpha=3$, but it gave err=-4.75456761. How can I control the error?

Comment: I also used your code under $\alpha=2$, and the error is -0.000016036. However, the eigenvalues are 8., 0.00126759, 0.000463182, -0.0000160364, -0.0000160233. Perhaps I have got it wrong (?)

Comment: I also used your code under $\alpha=3/2$, and the error is 0.0132175. The corresponding eigenvalues are 8.20329, 2.49182, 0.140025, 0.0132181, 0.0132175, which are all positive!

Comment: The calculation takes a long time - in some cases a few minutes. The 'error' is just the largest minimum eigenvalue achieved and it's prone to getting stuck in a well. Try a different method if it fails such as `Method->"RandomSearch". I couldn't manage to get another solution for the $\alpha=2$ case other than the trivial one.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/229348/23383  Would you please take a look at this? I have another similar problem there.

Comment: I post a similar problem here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240880/solve-a-system-consisting-of-inequalities-and-equations-with-lots-of-variables

Comment: I need some help or idea. Thank you.