# Determine a negative semidefinite 5*5 matrix

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues

I'd like to find the real parameters $\left\{p,\alpha ,a_{24},c_3,c_7,c_9,c_{10}\right\}$ in $M$, which is a $5\times 5$ real symmetric matrix, such that $M$ is negative semidefinite.
My code for $M$:

```
M={{2*(-1 + p)*(-p - α + p*α), 
   (1/2)*(((-1 + p)*(-2*p + (-1 + p)*α)*(-p + (-1 + p)*α))/p + 
     3*p*Subscript[c, 3]), 2*(-1 + p)*α, 
   (p*α - p^2*α - α^2 + p*α^2 + p^2*Subscript[c, 9])/(2*p), 
   (p*α - p^2*α + α^2 - 2*p*α^2 + p^2*α^2 + p^2*Subscript[c, 7])/p}, 
  {(1/2)*(((-1 + p)*(-2*p + (-1 + p)*α)*(-p + (-1 + p)*α))/p + 
     3*p*Subscript[c, 3]), (-3*p - α + p*α)*Subscript[c, 3], 
   (p*α - p^2*α + α^2 - 2*p*α^2 + p^2*α^2 + p^2*Subscript[c, 7])/(2*p), 
   Subscript[a, 24], (1/2)*(α*Subscript[c, 3] - 2*p*Subscript[c, 7] - 
     α*Subscript[c, 7] + p*α*Subscript[c, 7])}, 
  {2*(-1 + p)*α, (p*α - p^2*α + α^2 - 2*p*α^2 + p^2*α^2 + 
     p^2*Subscript[c, 7])/(2*p), -2*(p - α), 
   (2*p^2 - 3*p*α + α^2 + 3*p^2*Subscript[c, 10])/(2*p), 
   -(((-p)*α + p^2*α + α^2 - p*α^2 - p^2*Subscript[c, 9])/p)}, 
  {(p*α - p^2*α - α^2 + p*α^2 + p^2*Subscript[c, 9])/(2*p), 
   Subscript[a, 24], (2*p^2 - 3*p*α + α^2 + 3*p^2*Subscript[c, 10])/(2*p), 
   (-3*p + α)*Subscript[c, 10], (1/2)*(-2*p*Subscript[c, 9] + 
     α*Subscript[c, 9] - α*Subscript[c, 10] + p*α*Subscript[c, 10])}, 
  {(p*α - p^2*α + α^2 - 2*p*α^2 + p^2*α^2 + p^2*Subscript[c, 7])/p, 
   (1/2)*(α*Subscript[c, 3] - 2*p*Subscript[c, 7] - α*Subscript[c, 7] + 
     p*α*Subscript[c, 7]), -(((-p)*α + p^2*α + α^2 - p*α^2 - 
      p^2*Subscript[c, 9])/p), (1/2)*(-2*p*Subscript[c, 9] + 
     α*Subscript[c, 9] - α*Subscript[c, 10] + p*α*Subscript[c, 10]), 
   -2*Subscript[a, 24] - p*Subscript[c, 7] + α*Subscript[c, 7] - 
    p*Subscript[c, 9] - α*Subscript[c, 9] + p*α*Subscript[c, 9]}}
```

I assume that $\alpha>0$ and $0<p<1$. I have used the following code to determine the sign of the real eigenvalues of M.

```
evals = Eigenvalues[M]; {err, result} = NMinimize[Max[evals], Variables[M]]
```

It returns

```
{0.00016082723062714116, {p -> 1.3473043655754209, 
   α -> 0.00015509576526604037, Subscript[a, 24] -> 0.017641533025901306, 
   Subscript[c, 3] -> 0.23202376749144388, Subscript[c, 7] -> 
    -0.01818588251822145, Subscript[c, 9] -> -0.007611257690895714, 
   Subscript[c, 10] -> 0.6770944066001873}}
```

Then I input

```
Eigenvalues[M /. result]
```

and get

```
{-5.431161090012244, -1.8741889641145149, 0.00016083695648249602, 
  0.00015289932732631415, -0.00006302098327278627}
```

So $p=1.347304>1$ and there are 3 negative eigenvalues and 2 positive eigenvalues. My question is, how to modify the code (e.g. include the assumption $0<p<1$ in the code) or use alternative method to find the parameters such that $M$ is negative semidefinite (i.e. $M$ has 5 non-positive eigenvalues)?

Any reference, suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Look at the `NMinimize` documentation - you just add the constraint. `NMinimize[{Max[evals], 0<p<1}, Variables[M]]`

Comment: Thanks! I include the assumption $0<p<1$, but it returns {0.00022913, {p -> 1., \[Alpha] -> 0.294871, 
  Subscript[a, 24] -> -0.000906493, Subscript[c, 3] -> 0.0000525251, 
  Subscript[c, 7] -> -0.0000698797, Subscript[c, 9] -> 0.00593753, 
  Subscript[c, 10] -> 0.570851}}. Here in fact $p=0.9999999995213831`$. Does it follow from the result that we cannot find any parameters such that $M$ has 5 non-positive eigenvalues?

Comment: It does not follow - you'd need a symbolic proof for that.

Comment: From wikipedia _A matrix $M$ is negative (semi)definite if and only if $-M$ is positive (semi)definite._ So I tried the following: `{err, sol} = 
 With[{evals = Eigenvalues[-M]}, 
  NMaximize[{Min[evals], 0 < p < 1}, Variables[M]]];
NegativeSemidefiniteMatrixQ[M /. sol]` and I could not find an assignment which made `-M` positive semi-definite and `M` negative-semidefinite.

Comment: ^ futher to this, if you can find an assignment such that `cd = CholeskyDecomposition[-M];` has no imaginary parts, then `M` is negative semi-definite. However, `FindInstance[0 < p < 1 && (And @@ Thread[Im[cd] == 0]), Variables[M], Reals]` is not forthcoming - very slow.

Comment: I am trying to use -M to replace M, and so far I cannot get any parameters under which M is negative semidefinite.

Comment: It is also an goof idea to use Cholesky decomposition to find the parameters. I will try it.

Comment: For a given `p` you can show that it's impossible to get a Negative-semidefinite matrix using the [trace inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_symmetric_matrix#Trace) for positive-definiteness of `-M` like this: `m2 = M /. p -> 1/2;
With[{t1 = Tr[-m2],t2 = Tr[-m2]^2/Tr[MatrixPower[-m2, 2]]},
 Reduce[t1 > 0 && t2 > 5-1, Variables[m2]]
 ]` and the result is `False`.

Comment: So this result can be said to be a ‘symbolic proof’?

Comment: Yes I think so, but only for a given p. It hangs forever if you try to prove it for all 0<p<1.

Comment: What if the restriction $0<p<1$ is dropped out? For $p\not\in (0,1)$, any solution can be found?